# Problems with Manipulating a piecewise function

Tags: manipulate

I'm having problems with changing some parameters with "manipulate" in a piecewise function. The code i'm working with is:

```
f[x_] := -x /; x <= 0
f[x_] := 3 x + x^2 /; 0 < x <= 3
f[x_] := (-3 x + 28 + n) /; x > 3
Manipulate[Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 15}], {n, 0, 15, 1}]
```

The problem is that if I leave the n the last part of the function won't even show up. Is there any easy way to fix this or is some extensive coding needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `n` as an input of your function:

```
f[x_, n_] := -x /; x <= 0
f[x_, n_] := 3 x + x^2 /; 0 < x <= 3
f[x_, n_] := (-3 x + 28 + n) /; x > 3
Manipulate[Plot[f[x, n], {x, -5, 15}, PlotRange -> {-30, 35},
  Exclusions -> {3}], {n, -15, 15, 1}]
```

This isn't an issue with piecewise functions, it's just an issue with manipulate. In your original version, the manipulate command doesn't understand how to plug in n=0, 1, 2, etc. into the function f[x], so it does nothing. THEN after the manipulate has tried to do the plot of `f[x]`, and it does that, except now there is an `n` in your function that has cropped up (important) after the manipulate attempted to plug in for all the `n` symbols. That's why you should use the variable `n` explicitly.

(I also added an exclusion since you don't want a weird vertical line segment at x=3 and changed the plot range and manipulate range a bit. That's just style stuff.)

Comment: short and to the point, good explanation too. thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, the piecewise function can be defined using `Piecewise`. As  pointed out by Kellen Myers, there is discontinuity at $x=3$. I have just 'joined the plot'.

```
f[x_, n_] := Piecewise[{{-x, x <= 0},
   {3 x + x^2, 0 < x <= 3}, {-3 x + 28 + n, x > 3}}];
```

Visualizing:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[x, n], {x, -5, 15}, Exclusions -> None, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 40}], {n, 0, 15, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: A great answer as well, thank you :)

Comment: @user350 thanks, post for completeness